# Memory Mapping (mmap) Linux Device Driver in Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, java-native-interface, linux-device-driver, mmap

I have a device driver which controls a specific hardware. I would like to access the hardware directly from the user application running in Java/Scala through MMAP. Here's a stripped down version of the code I have:

```
val fc = new RandomAccessFile(new File("/dev/device"),"rw").getChannel()
val buf = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE,0,bufferSize)
fc.read(buf)
```

Here's the error I get when I run the code:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.truncate0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.truncate(FileDispatcherImpl.java:80)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:858)
at Main$$anon$1.<init>(mmap.Scala:12)
```

I have already looked at a similar post here: [How to memory map (mmap) a linux block device (e.g. /dev/sdb) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901832/how-to-memory-map-mmap-a-linux-block-device-e-g-dev-sdb-in-java) which describe the problem; however, there is not suggestion of how to fix it. I am aware of Java Native Interface (JNI) but it's crucial for me to access hardware directly from Java framework. Can anyone suggest a way to modify Java source file to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18904842/4428462), also from the link you posted _"If you absolutely need to do this within Java you may need to do read() calls and write() calls of the appropriate length and offset."_ I don't know anything about this, but did you try that ?

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that and I have read and write system calls implemented for other aspects of my device driver but those doesn't help much with respect to doing Direct I/O. I also tried to play around with the bufferSize but it doesn't work since the size of the device file is zero which I think is the cause of the problem in the first place. I am not very familiar with Java to know if it'd be possible to manipulate the fileChannel.map file in order to avoid truncating the size.